# utfsym with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

### UPDATE

The new version of `utfsym.sty` released 2022/04/17 works with all engines.

---

Why can't we use XeLaTeX with the `utfsym` package? Is there any way to solve the problem? The following is a minimal working sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{utfsym}

\begin{document}
\usym{2680} Many
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, I know a solution to invoke some specific symbol which permits to use XeLaTeX or LulaLaTeX: if we want to invoke the symbold coded as `abcd`, we just need to find the `abcd.tikz` file [in the package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/utfsym/source) and copy the codes in the `abcd.tikz` file into the following blank.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\heart}{\mathord{%
\resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`M}{%

}%
}%
}%
\makeatother
```

For example, if we want to invoke the symbol coded as `2665`, then we get the codes and output as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\heart}{\mathord{%
\resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`M}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(100.0,1876.0)},nonzero rule]
  \path[draw=.,fill=.,line width=1.600pt] (1460.0000,-1216.0000) ..
    controls (1460.0000,-1126.0000) and (1430.6667,-1028.3333) ..
    (1372.0000,-923.0000) .. controls (1335.3333,-857.0000) and
    (1276.0000,-772.3333) .. (1194.0000,-669.0000) .. controls
    (1082.0000,-527.6667) and (1001.0000,-417.6667) .. (951.0000,-339.0000) ..
    controls (869.0000,-211.0000) and (812.0000,-87.6667) .. (780.0000,31.0000) ..
    controls (748.0000,-87.6667) and (691.0000,-211.0000) .. (609.0000,-339.0000)
    .. controls (559.0000,-417.6667) and (478.0000,-527.6667) ..
    (366.0000,-669.0000) .. controls (284.0000,-772.3333) and (224.6667,-857.0000)
    .. (188.0000,-923.0000) .. controls (129.3333,-1028.3333) and
    (100.0000,-1126.0000) .. (100.0000,-1216.0000) .. controls
    (100.0000,-1308.0000) and (131.6667,-1384.3333) .. (195.0000,-1445.0000) ..
    controls (258.3333,-1505.6667) and (336.3333,-1536.0000) ..
    (429.0000,-1536.0000) .. controls (514.3333,-1536.0000) and
    (590.3333,-1504.3333) .. (657.0000,-1441.0000) .. controls
    (719.6667,-1381.6667) and (760.6667,-1308.6667) .. (780.0000,-1222.0000) ..
    controls (799.3333,-1308.6667) and (840.3333,-1381.6667) ..
    (903.0000,-1441.0000) .. controls (969.6667,-1504.3333) and
    (1045.6667,-1536.0000) .. (1131.0000,-1536.0000) .. controls
    (1223.6667,-1536.0000) and (1301.6667,-1505.6667) .. (1365.0000,-1445.0000) ..
    controls (1428.3333,-1384.3333) and (1460.0000,-1308.0000) ..
    (1460.0000,-1216.0000) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Huge
$\heart$ Many things

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it seems a little complicated, is there any simple solution to invoke some specific symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ufsym` is a package that appears to use multiple

```
 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

to map Unicode code points to characters drawn with tikz suitable for pdftex, it is not needed in xetex or luatex that can directly typeset Unicode code points using Unicode Opentype fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\symbol{"2680} Many ⚀ Many
\end{document}
```

---

If you want the tikz versions of these characers not real fonts evn with xetex, you can hide the `inputenc`  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% hide inputenc commands
\makeatletter
\def\DeclareUnicodeCharacter#1#2{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{utfsym}

\begin{document}

\usym{2680} Many 
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I want to invoke symbols in `utfsym` and I have to use XeLaTeX to compile my file.

Comment: @M.Logic oh wait a minute you can probably access the tikz, give me a minute...

Comment: I updated the statements.

Comment: @M.Logic try now

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE

The new version of `utfsym.sty` released 2022/04/17 works with all engines.

---

### OLD ANSWER

It would be easy to make `utfsym` to work with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

### File `xutfsym.sty`

The file has been cut, but the modification of `utfsym.sty` is straightforward: just change the part up to the first `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` with what's below and change all occurrences of `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` with `\xutfsym@declare`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{xutfsym}[2022/04/16 Use TikZ to support icons from Unicode blocks ]
%% developed for use in package 'schule' 2016 by Daniel Spittank
%% this package is public domain, CC0
%% modified to work with (Xe|Lua)LaTeX (egreg)

%% - needs ut8 as input encoding
%% - TikZ paths are extracted from Symbola.ttf public domain font by George Douros,
%%   see: http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/
%% - supports direct use of unicode symbols
%% - supports textcolor
%% - supports fontsizes
%% - supported Blocks:
%%   - Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows (2600-26FF)
%%   - Dingbats (2700-27BF)
%%   - Mahjong Tiles (1F000-1F02F)
%%   - Domino Tiles (1F030-1F09F)
%%   - Playing Cards (1F0A0-1F0FF)
%%   - Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs (1F300-1F5FF)
%%   - Emoticons / Emoji (1F600-1F64F)
%%   - Transport and Map Symbols (1F680-1F6FF)

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{iftex}

%% command for symbol usage \usym{unicode number}
\newcommand{\usym}[1]{\resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`M}{\input{usym#1.tikz}}}

%% command for symbol usage as a picture, scaling by height
%% \usymH{unicode number}{height}
\newcommand{\usymH}[2]{\resizebox{!}{#2}{\input{usym#1.tikz}}}

%% command for symbol usage as a picture, scaling by width
%% \usymW{unicode number}{width}
\newcommand{\usymW}[2]{\resizebox{#2}{!}{\input{usym#1.tikz}}}

\iftutex
  % unicode engine
  \def\xutfsym@declare#1#2{%
    \begingroup\lccode`~="#1\lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}{#2}%
    \catcode"#1=\active
  }%
\else
  \let\xutfsym@declare\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
\fi

%% direct unicode support
\xutfsym@declare{1F000}{\usym{1F000}}
\xutfsym@declare{1F001}{\usym{1F001}}
% many other similar lines where the original
% file has \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
% I had to cut because of size limit in answers
% Up to the following one
\xutfsym@declare{27BF}{\usym{27BF}}

\endinput
```

### Test

Now you can try the following input file with either `pdflatex` or `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xutfsym}

\begin{document}

♠ 

\usym{2660} \usym{1F000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is exactly the same with both engines.

### Comments

A possible development is to add a check whether the character is available in the current font so not to need to `\input` a Ti*k*Z picture.

Comment: So I think the codes of the package which has a lot of beautiful symbols should be written in this way or @David Carlisle 's way. Then it would be more convenient. Maybe you could sent the question and answers to the author of the package.

Comment: @M.Logic Mail sent

Comment: By the way, a few unicodes, for example, unicodes 2605 and 2606, in the package are also in most of the Chinese fonts, and so if we write the package in this way and also invoke such Chinese fonts, will they conflict with each other?

Comment: @M.Logic No, with the check I proposed to the authors and mentioned in the final paragraph.

Comment: I comment `[...]` since otherwise it will produce errors.

Comment: @M.Logic As I wrote, the site poses a limit on the size of the messages, so I had to cut the code. There are *many* other declarations like those that, in `utfsym.sty` have `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, which has to be replaced by `\xutfsym@declare`

Comment: I see! Thanks very much!

Comment: `begingroup\lccode\`~="#1\lowercase{\endgroup\protected\def~}` I actually did that in the first version of my answer, but decided to simply drop it for unicode texs, partly to keep the answer simple, and partly as I'm not sure making characters active is "the xetex way" when the symbols are available using the command form.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle One might want to type in the characters themselves.

Comment: One might, but probably should not if you are not getting font data (arguably)

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version, which can be found at https://gitlab.com/gi-fg-ibnw/utfsym.

Comment: Thanks for your update on the package!